# Jetpack button location buffering

Tags: plugin-jetpack

Is there a simple way to add a buffer or spacing to the location of the Jetpack social icons to move it further to the right of its default location when placed at the top of a page? I want to add a buffer of about 8 spaces to make it line up with the image on my opening page so it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use FireBug to inspect the HTML element holding the social icons. If the container has an ID assigned such as:

```
  <div id="social-icons"> ... </div>
```

you can style it using CSS by adding some margin:

```
  #social-icons img {
    margin: 8px;
  }
```